# Freezing the UI in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

The following code is freezing my UI. Cant do any actions.

```
- (void) longPoll {
    //create an autorelease pool for the thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSError* error = nil;
        NSURLResponse* response = nil;
        NSURL* requestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl"];
        NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:requestUrl];

        //send the request (will block until a response comes back)
        NSData* responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                     returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self dataReceived:responseData];
        });
    });
        //compose the request


        //pass the response on to the handler (can also check for errors here, if you want)


        //clear the pool

    }




- (void) startPoll {
    //not covered in this example:  stopping the poll or ensuring that only 1 poll is active at any given time
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(longPoll) withObject: nil];
}

- (void) dataReceived: (NSData*) theData {
    //process the response here
    NSDictionary *dict=[theData JSONValue];
   [self ParseJson:dict];
     [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(longPoll) withObject: nil];
}
```

Can anyone give me the exact reason for it or any alternative to do the similar code for continues polling.

Comment: No need of calling `dataReceived:` inside the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{`

Comment: check what do you do in [self ParseJson:dict]; Only it can freeze UI.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an infinite loop:

`longCall` calls `dataReceived` calls `longCall` etc....

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you want to do. There is infinite loop between     longPool and     dataReceived
there should be mechanism where you stop this call and you can use

```
@autorelease {} block for create autorelease pool in ARC Enabled project and
NSAutoReleasePool class obj for Without ARC.
```